# Moving PDF files from a SQL Server Table to Blob Storage

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to move PDF files from the Azure SQL Server database table to Blob Storage and running into some trouble.

I am trying to use the SQL Server stored procedure `sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint` to accomplish this task.  The issue is it is converting my file to Unicode before transmitting:

Here is my code

```
DECLARE @bytes VARBINARY(MAX) = NULL;
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL;

SELECT TOP 1 @bytes = Bytes, @fileName = FileName
FROM #TempPdf
OPTION(RECOMPILE);

DECLARE @response VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL;
DECLARE @storageContainerUrl VARCHAR(MAX) = 'https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/testing-pdfs/';

DECLARE @url VARCHAR(MAX) = CONCAT(@storageContainerUrl, @fileName);
DECLARE @payload VARCHAR(MAX) = @bytes;
DECLARE @payloadLength INT = DATALENGTH(@payload);

DECLARE @headers VARCHAR(1000) = JSON_OBJECT
(
        'content-length': @payloadLength,
        'x-ms-content-length': CAST(@payloadLength AS VARCHAR(20)),
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'application/xml',
        'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob'
);

SELECT
@bytes AS Bytes,
DATALENGTH(@bytes) AS BytesLength,
@payload AS Payload,
DATALENGTH(@payload) AS PayloadLength;

EXEC sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint
    @url = @url,
    @method = 'PUT',
    @headers = @headers,
    @payload = @payload,
    @credential = 'MyCredentials',
    @response = @response OUTPUT;

SELECT CAST(@response AS XML) AS Response;
```

The data length of both the bytes(`VARBINARY(MAX)`) and payload(`VARCHAR(MAX)`) is `88,698`, which is correct for this PDF.  However, when I look at the size in Blob Storage it is 127KiB, which is larger than 87Ki it should be.

I believe it doing this because `sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint` parameter `@payload` is a `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, so it's converting my 8-bit variable to Unicode, which is causing file corruption.

Is there a way to use `sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint` without file corruption or an alternative way of doing this in a stored procedure?

If all else fails, I will just have to accomplish this using C# and create some type of temporary job.

Thanks!

Comment: So what would be the issue and how do you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

A PDF is a binary file.  You can't just convert it to a `varchar(max)` and send it as a string.  You must send it as binary data.  But sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint doesn't accept binary payloads because it's for calling REST endpoints.

So you'll need an Azure function or similar to do this.  You can either have the function read the PDF from Azure SQL and write the blob, or have it accept the PDF data encoded in Base64 or hex string encoded as a string from sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint and decode it to a binary file and write it to storage.

Comment: I have done that too.  So when I do this `@payload = @bytes, -- @byte is a VARBINARY(MAX)` .  This makes the file size in Blob Storage even larger.  When I look at the Blob Storage version of the file with a hex editor, it shows Chinese characters instead of PDF headers.  I believe this happens because of the conversion from `VARBINARY(MAX)` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

Comment: Right.  If you try to pass a binary value it will be converted to a NVARCHAR(MAX).  You simply can't pass binary values with sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint.  The payload must be a string.

Comment: So are you saying there is no way to accomplish what I'm trying to do with `sp_invoke_external_rest_endpoint`?

Comment: You can convert to base64 first

Comment: @siggemannen I tried `DECLARE @payload VARCHAR(MAX) = BASE64_ENCODE(@bytes);` and that also didn't work.

Comment: Didn't work is a very broad statement...

Comment: The file is `115 KiB` in Blob Storage instead of the expected `87Kib`.  When downloading the Blob Storage version of the file and viewing it in a hex editor the bytes are in base64 instead of PDF.

Comment: Right.  Because what you're trying won't work.  A Base64 string is still just a string, and will create a text file, not a PDF file.

Comment: Agreed.  So can you give me an example on how to make this work?

Comment: You can't do this in TSQL in Azure SQL Database.  So, eg with C#, read the binary file from SQL Server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-binary-data and write it to Blob storage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload

Comment: I’m really confused on why Microsoft designed it with the limitation of only allowing Unicode payloads.

Comment: Because it's for calling REST APIs, which typically use JSON as the payload.  It's not a general purpose HTTP API for interacting with arbitrary HTTP endpoints.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft If one of the endpoints you're advertising is Blob Storage,  it really seems to be an artificial limitation if you're forcing only Unicode data.